BLE scanner with pending intent does not provide scanResults
Trying to use startScan with pending intent. The broadcast receiver is invoked however the provided intent does not have any extras (and does not have any scan result in the intent). This code worked fine in an older android version.
This is my scanner:
fun ComponentActivity.startScanner() {
    if (!checkForPermission(
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            }
            else {
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            }
    )){
        return
    }

    with(logViewModel) {
        if (!haveBtPermissions) {
            haveBtPermissions = true
            clear()
        }
    }

//    bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)
    bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, pendingIntent)
    Log.i(TAG, "Scanner started")
}

private val filters get() = mutableListOf<ScanFilter>().apply {
    val filterShortServiceUUID = ScanFilter.Builder()
        .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString ("0000${"180D"}-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
        .build()
    add(filterShortServiceUUID)
}

private val settings get() = ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(
    ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED
).build()

private val ComponentActivity.bluetoothAdapter get() = (applicationContext
    .getSystemService(ComponentActivity.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager).adapter

private val ComponentActivity.pendingIntent get() =
    applicationContext.let {appContext ->
        val intent = Intent(appContext, DeviceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
//            .setAction("com.solvek.bletrigger.ACTION_FOUND")

        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            appContext, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )!!
    }

private fun ComponentActivity.checkForPermission(permission: String): Boolean {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            permission
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return true
    }

    with(logViewModel) {
        append("Please grant permissions and restart app!")
        haveBtPermissions = false
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
            startScanner()
        }.launch(arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
        ))
    }

    return false
}

Receiver
class DeviceBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "===== A new message received")
        if (context == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Context is null")
            return
        }

        if (intent == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Intent is null")
            return
        }

        val bleCallbackType: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeScanner.EXTRA_CALLBACK_TYPE, -1)
        if (bleCallbackType == -1){
            Log.w(TAG, "Callback type not specified")
            return
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Received callback type $bleCallbackType")

and manifest
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Request Bluetooth permissions for devices on API 31,32. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        tools:targetApi="s" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
             devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!-- Since Bluetooth is a basic requirement for our app -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
...

        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="com.solvek.bletrigger.ACTION_FOUND" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
        </receiver>


Bluetooth scan permission is a run-time permissions and must therefore be requested at run-time. Checking the permissions is not sufficient.

Thanks but I do request permissions in runtime: registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
startScanner()
}.launch(arrayOf(
Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
))

In my opinion, it might be useful to follow Goggle's guidelines.
"ScanCallback, which is the interface used to deliver BLE scan results"
See https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/find-ble-devices
In my app, for example, I used the following code:
    private val scanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    /**
     * step 12 (4 sc) Bluetooth scan callback
     * Refer to [bignerdranch.com](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/
     * and https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-2/ )
     * By [Andrew Lunsford](https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-lunsford-403b4b6/)
     *
     * @param callbackType int
     * @param result ScanResult
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        val device: BluetoothDevice = result.getDevice()
        // ...do whatever you want with this found device
        if (!devicesArrayList.contains(device)) {
            devicesArrayList.add(device)
            deviceAddressFound = device.address!!
            connect(deviceAddressFound)
        }
    }
    override fun onBatchScanResults(results: List<ScanResult?>?) {
        // Ignore for now
    }

